# Indefinite integral resulting in inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I tried to find an answer to this question but found nothing, maybe because I don't know how to properly formulate it. I hope I can make myself understood here.

The thing is, recently I started learning about indefinite integrals in school and my teacher told us that the derivatives of inverse trigonometric functions have two indefinite integrals. For example:

$$\int\frac1{1+x^2}dx=\arctan(x)+C=-\text{arccot}(x)+C$$

Which makes sense since the derivatives of related inverse trigonometric functions differ just in the sign. Nonetheless, this clashes with my notion that there must be only one result for any given argument of a function. Moreover, when I looked it up on the Internet I noticed that most websites just show the positive indefinite integrals. My question is whether the indefinite integrals of the derivatives of inverse trigonometric functions have in fact two different results and, if that's the case, why is it like that?

Comment: The two different anti-derivatives differ by a constant which is allowed in anti-differentiation. Indeed, $\arctan(x) + \arccos(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. This highlights the importance of adding the $+C$ after taking an antiderivative.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Of course! You're totally right. I forgot to take into consideration the meaning of the constant of integration. Now this makes perfect sense! So, are both considered results of the indefinite integral or is only one of them the usual one?

By the way, thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: Both are completely correct answers, however it is more usual and standard to see arctan as the result.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Now I see. Many thanks! Incidentally, I just noticed that in your first comment you wrote $\arccos(x)$ instead of $\text{arccot}(x)$. It's not a big deal, I just wanted to let you know :)

Comment: Yes, you're 100% right. I meant to write inverse cotangent! Sorry about that.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts No problem!